# pyCharmを使ってimportができない

Tags: python, python3

pycharmをつかってtweepyをいじろうとしているのですが、test.pyにtweetapiをimportで読み込ませたいのですが読み込んでくれません。
何度やってもNo module named '**main**.tweetapi'; '**main**' is not a packageというエラーが出ます。助けてください[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from.tweetapi import api
```

これを

```
from tweetapi import api
```

これで動きませんか？

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。